# Magento adding referer param to getLoginPostUrl()

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to create a form that integrates the login into the process as seamlessly as possible.

I'm using `Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginPostUrl()` at the moment for the login form, if there is something better to use I'm all ears, and it works, but it ends up at the user dashboard.

I looked up the function and its looking for
`if($this->_getRequest()->getParam(self::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME)){`
but I'm not sure how to give it the param in a way that the function will read it.

I noticed if I use `Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl()` it adds the referer itself, so I traced it and found how it adds the encoded referer to the url and ended up with this

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginPostUrl(); ?>referer/<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($this->getUrl("frontname/controller/function")); ?>
```

Which gives me a url that looks like this

```
http://www.mysite.com/customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cDovL3J5YW4uZGV2L3VzL2Zyb250bmFtZS9jb250cm9sbGVyL2Z1bmN0aW9uLw,,/
```

Which works, but I'm thinking there has to be a better way. Anyone have any idea?

If not... that works for me, in case anyone else is looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

I've done it in this way, hope this helps for somebody as well:

```
Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($this->getUrl("frontname/controller/function"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Your customers are being redirected to the dashboard because of a setting in your configuration. Go to

> System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options

And turn "Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" to "No". Magento will start to listen to that referrer parameter and put your customers back to the page they were on before they clicked "Login".

I know this is an old thread and it's probably way to late to help, but this question ranks for the problem, maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I would combine *vladislav-mosalsky*'s answer with the `_current` snippet from *amardeep-aryan* so that you only need one copy of the code to use.

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(
    Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(
        Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true))
    )))
);
```

Comment: What do I have to put inside action attribute in the form? Where does it go your code? In header.phtml?

Comment: ^ I don't understand your question.

Comment: The code you've posted must go where? Does it go inside the form action or needed to put into header.phtml ?

Comment: That whole snippet is for redirecting right when PHP hits that code, so inside a controller in the saveAction for instance. If you're just looking for a way to generate the URL, then just use the inner two Mage::getURL calls.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this ways.

**Step 1.**

*System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options*

And turn "*Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in*" to "**No**". Magento will start to listen to that referrer parameter and put your customers back to the page they were on before they clicked "Login".

**Step 2.**

In header.phtml

```
if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() and $this->getRequest()->getControllerName() != 'account'){
     $referer = Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode(Mage::getUrl('', array('_current' => true,'_use_rewrite' => true)));
     Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCustomRefererUrl($referer);
}
```

**Step 3.**

In login form

```
 <?php $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME); 
    echo Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginpost', array('referer' => $referer)); ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
```

It should work fine.