# Magento customer login form on CMS page not working

Tags: php, forms, magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to get a login form that has been called by a CMS page to work but when tested, it redirects back to the page and doesn't log the user in.

I guess this is to do with not having the right form key as I notice the default login page has the URL format,

> www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/referer/blahblahblah/

and the form calls the function, `getPostActionUrl()` which generates this URL for the form action,

> www.mydomain.com/customer/account/loginPost/referer/blahblahblah/

So how do I get my form to use that blahblahblah key?

The form does generate a hidden input called `form_key`. This isn't the same as blahblahblah though.

Here is the code of the form. Can anyone suggest how to get the blahblahblah key and where to drop it in the form code?

```
<div class="block block-login">
<div class="block-title">
    <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></strong>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('customer.form.login.extra')?>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
    <div class="block-content">
        <label for="mini-login"><?php echo $this->__('Email:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Email Address')) ?>" />
        <label for="mini-password"><?php echo $this->__('Password:') ?></label>
        <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Password')) ?>" />
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Login')) ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
//]]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work with a bit of research.

First of all, I found this thread: [Magento adding referer param to getLoginPostUrl()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241289/magento-adding-referer-param-to-getloginposturl)

That gave me the basis for a partially successful solution.

First off, in

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cms/cmslogin.phtml

(a custom file I created for this login form)

I replaced,

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
```

with,

```
<?php $referer = $this->getRequest()->getParam(Mage_Customer_Helper_Data::REFERER_QUERY_PARAM_NAME); 
echo Mage::helper('core')->urlDecode($referer);
?>
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/loginPost', array('referer' => $referer)); ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
```

It seems that was all that was needed to get the login form working.

The problem I have now is that, despite "Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Login Options > Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in" being set to NO, the form is redirecting to the Dashboard - I want it to redirect back to the CMS page (which when the user is logged in and a member of a particular customer group, shows different content). Will ask this separately.